# In Ruby, is it illegal to put an "after-the-value-if-expression" inside of a block?

Tags: ruby, syntax, if-statement

### Error:

```
rescue_from 'NotAuthorizedException' do |exception|
    a = 'b' if true else 'c'
end
```

### No error:

```
rescue_from 'NotAuthorizedException' do |exception|
    a = 'b'
end
```

The error I'm getting is: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end`

Am I missing something obvious? This happens even when I add parentheses around the method argument: `rescue_from('NotAuthorizedException') ...`.

### Update:

Well, sepp2k is right: the syntax isn't valid. **However**, the following method results in the `object` being raised as an exception with the value `'a'`, at least when run within my Rails app. I'm going to try to create a reproducible stand-alone program in which this syntax *seems* to be valid.

```
def test
  object = 'a' if true else 'b'
  raise object.to_yaml
end
```

### Update 2:

It works in `irb` (without the `to_yaml`), but the following warning is shown:

```
warning: else without rescue is useless
```

### Update 3:

```
def test
  object = 'a' if true else 'b'
end
```

This results in the same warning, but `'b'` is displayed. I'm done digging!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 'b' if true else 'c'
```

is invalid syntax in ruby whether it's in a block or not (you're probably thinking of python where the syntax is legal). You need to either use

```
a = if true then 'b' else 'c' end
```

or

```
a = true ? 'b' : 'c'
```

Comment: Are you sure it's invalid? I have the same syntax later: `object  = model_class.find(params[:id]) if params[:id] else model_class`. I'm going to experiment, because the code I just pasted is *definitely* executed every request...

Comment: +1 Hmmm. `irb` vomited when I tried that syntax. I wonder whether the code I pasted is somehow being mixed with what's on the next line! I'll be back in a moment.

Comment: @Closure: Entering that very line into `ruby -c` (or `irb` for that matter) gives a SyntaxError in ruby 1.8.7 as well as 1.9.2 (and presumably in all other ruby versions as well), so yes, I'm sure. I honestly can't tell you why it seems to work for you.

Comment: Here is another way to do it: a = if true then 'b' else 'c' end

Comment: @beach: Yes, of course, I wasn't really thinking when I put the `a=` inside the `if`.

Comment: Personally I prefer the ternary `(test) ? true_value : false_value` form, but I come from a C and Perl background. I find it a lot easier to understand for simple conditionals, and often is cleaner for more complex ones.